# Years to Decades

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have a df called 'va' with a column 'contest_id' that contains a year value. For example, a record in the years column would say 73hod34 with the year being 1973. I would like to make a column that takes the first character so I can code my data in terms of decades rather than years.

Additionally I have a 'years' column ('1973' == 1973) but for some reason I can't cast it from string to integer. If there's a way to do that or some time series value I could change that to then maybe that could be a fix?

The following code returned a column that just repeated the entry for 'years':

```
va['decade'] = va[['contest_id']].apply(lambda x: x[0], axis = 1)
```

Also tried

```
va['decade'] = va[['contest_id']].apply(lambda x: x[:0], axis = 1)
```

Some data, as requested:

[Screenshot of my data from Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVv2i.png)

And to reiterate, I want to add a third column with the decade, even if it's just one digit (like 7 for the 1970s)
Thanks in advance for the assist!

Comment: `[:0]` will always be empty.

Comment: Can you post some of the data?

Comment: did you try va['year'] = va['year'].astype(int) to convert the years column to type int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the year's column, I don't think there is a need to subset the string of contest_id, but here are two solutions to create a decade's column.
Since you need to represent the year with some int value, you could convert it to a category(factor) instead: 
This will yield the column with entire year name as a factor.

```
va['decade'] = va['year'].astype('category')
```

or alternatively, try:

```
va['decade'] = (va['contest_id'].apply(lambda x: x[:2])).astype('category')
```

Comment: The second one worked! I changed it to lambda x: x[:1] to get the first digit and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!